Sort GoogleSheets table that has a "unique" formula
I couldnt find a way to describe my problem properly on my title.
This is my scenario:
I have an table that contains all my variables of interests. Lets says all of them are in ColumnB.

There is another table containing values for some of those variables. Lets say variables are in ColumnD and values are in ColumnE.

My main objective here is creating another table summarazing Variables and it's values. One row per variable.
So I am using "UNIQUE" formula, in order to get unique variables, combined with an simple "SUMIFS" as shown in image below.


The problem:
How can I order this result table by the "TOTAL VALUE" column ? Is it even possible ?
I am attaching this google sheets file here.
Any help is appreciated

Here's something you can try:
=let(
variables,B3:B7,
table,map(variables,lambda(t,hstack(t,sumif(D:D,t,E:E)))),
sort(table,2,0))

Documentation: Let function, Map function, HStack function, and Sort function.

You can use:
=SORT({B3:B7,SUMIF(D3:D,B3:B7,E3:E)},2,) 

